# what does $[0,1]^\omega$ mean

Tags: general-topology, notation

The question is,

Give $[0,1]^\omega$ the uniform topology, find an infinite subset of this space that has no limit point.

I just want to know what does $[0,1]^\omega$ mean so I can proceed.

I'd appreciate any explanation.

Comment: $\omega=\mathbb N$, the set of all integers. (The notation $\omega$ is usually used when doing ordinal arithmetic; the expression $\omega+2$ means $\omega\cup\{\omega,\omega\cup\{\omega\}\}$, but the expression $\mathbb N+2$ means nothing.

Comment: Are you working out of *Munkres*?

Comment: Yes. It's the first question on page 181.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0,1]^\omega$ is defined as the set of sequences $(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ with $x_j \in [0,1]$.

The uniform topology in $[0,1]^\omega$ is defined as:

$x = \{x_i : i < \omega\}$

$y = \{y_j : j < \omega\}$

$p(x,y) = \sup\{\overline{d} (x_i, y_i) : i < \omega\}$

(Just taking it from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293328/how-to-show-that-0-1-omega-is-not-locally-compact-in-the-uniform-topology) post, which seems to be dealing with a similar problem)

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1]^{\omega}$ is the set of infinite sequences of elements of $[0,1]$, i.e. the set of all sequences
$$(x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots)$$
such that $x_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$.

Comment: What is the uniform topology? I haven't heard of this before.

Comment: @user46944 I think it is something from OP's textbook, particular if he/she are using *Munkres*

Comment: The uniform topology is generated by the metric $\bar{d}(x,y)=\max(d(x,y),1)$, if I didn't remember wrongly.

Comment: @JustinZhou What's the metric $d$?

Comment: @user46944 In case of $\mathbb{R}$, it's just the distance.

Comment: @JustinZhou Sure, but we aren't in $\Bbb R$.  We are in the space of sequences with coordinates in $[0,1]$.  Hmm...

Comment: @user46944 First it should be $\bar{d}(x,y)=\min (d(x,y),1)$. And in this question, my understanding is that it is the infinite Cartesian product of $[0,1]$ with uniform topology.

Comment: @JustinZhou Oh, I see.  So it sounds like we define $\overline{d}$ on $[0,1]$ and look at its topology, then take the product topology on the Cartesian product.

Comment: @user46944 [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293328/how-to-show-that-0-1-omega-is-not-locally-compact-in-the-uniform-topology) may be relevant

Comment: @Soke It's definitely relevant.